# My Kendo chart is not filtered in a proper way

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2010, kendo-ui

I have a kendo chart with group field and also have tree-view with  3 check-boxes.I want to filter the graph with the check-box checked event.but in my application it is not working.please any one help me.
my chart code is

```
    $("#myChart").kendoChart({
    theme: $(document).data("kendoSkin") || "default",
    dataSource: {
    data: tmpData2,
    sort: {
            field: "date",
            dir: "asc"
        },
    group: {
            field: "close"
        },
        schema: {
            model: {
                fields: {
                    date: {
                        type: "date"  }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    title: {
        text: "My Date-aware Chart"
    },
    legend: {
        position: "bottom"
    },
    seriesDefaults: {
        type: "line",
        labels: {
            visible: true
        },
        missingValues: "gap"
    },
    series: [{
        name: "Close",
        field: "closeA",
        axis: "A"
    },

    {
        name: "Close",
        field: "closeb",
        axis: "B"
    },
             {      name: "Close",
        field: "closec",
        axis: "B"
         }],
        valueAxis: [{
        name: "A",
        labels: {
            format: "{0}%"
        }
    },
    {
        name: "B",
        labels: {
            format: "{0}D"
        }
    }],
    categoryAxis: {
        type: "Date",
        field: "date",
        axisCrossingValue: [0, 1000]
    }

});
```

and my tree-view code is

```
    $("#treeview").on("change", function (e) {
        console.log("click", multi.text());
        var selected = multi.text().split(",");
        console.log("multi", selected);
        var condition = {
            logic  : "or",
            filters: [
            ]
        };
        $.each(selected, function (idx, elem) {
            condition.filters.push({ field: " close", operator: "eq", value: elem.trim() });
        });
        mychart.dataSource.filter(condition);
    });
```

Comment: here is the fiddle   http://jsfiddle.net/RHh67/15/

Comment: That jsfiddle fails with a JavaScript error "multi is not defined". Fix that first.

Comment: sorry that code is not required so delete that one here is the updated fiddle   http://jsfiddle.net/RHh67/36/

Comment: Now it fails with "selected is not defined".

Comment: ya,here is fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/RHh67/39/.   Check this once,and please modify this.

Comment: The latest fiddle again fails with "multi is not defined". I recommend checking your browser's console for errors.

Comment: don't mind,here is the fiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/RHh67/40/,check it once

Comment: Now it doesn't work because you are doing $("#mychart").data("kendoGrid"). Use this instead: $("#mychart").data("kendoChart"). Debugging your code would help a lot.

Comment: ya,tried that but no result here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/RHh67/41/

Comment: Probably because the id of your chart is "myChart" not "mychart". The casing is important.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think I now understand what your requirement is. You need to remove series from the chart when checking the treeview. This should be implemented by removing series from the chart configuration and then calling the `refresh` method:

```
// All series
var series = [{
    name: "Close",
    field: "closeA",
    axis: "A"
},
{
     name: "Close",
     field: "closeb",
     axis: "B"
},
{      
     name: "Close",
     field: "closec",
     axis: "B"
}
];

$("#treeview").on("change", function (e) {
    var chart = $("#myChart").data("kendoChart");

    // Start with empty series
    var checkedSeries = [];

    // Iterate all checked checkboxes in the treeview
    $("#treeview").find(":checked").each(function() {
        // Get the checked node's text - it is the grand parent of the checkbox element
        var nodeText = $(this).parent().parent().text();

        // Find the series whose field is the same as the node's text
        $.each(series, function(index, series) {
            if (series.field == nodeText) {
                // add it to the checkedSeries array
                checkedSeries.push(series);
            }
        });
    });

    // Set the chart series
    chart.options.series = checkedSeries;
    // Refresh the chart
    chart.refresh();
});
```

Here is the updated jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RHh67/43/

Comment: Thank you so much Atanas Korchev.